# Why non zero wedge term in curvature form?

Tags: differential-topology, physics, differential-forms, curvature

The definition of the curvature form ( from Wikipedia ) is:

$$ \Omega = d \omega + \frac{1}{2} [ \omega \wedge \omega ] $$

I am puzzled about the rightmost term. According to what I have learned so far, the wedge product of a one-form with itself is always zero. So shouldn't the $ \omega \wedge \omega $ term simply be zero?

My best guess is that my "learnings" don't work on curved manifolds. Since I am a beginner physics student ( with almost zero math knowledge ), I am having a hard time finding the answer in math literature. Can someone give me a low-brow answer to this naive question? Thanks.

Motivation for question: I stumbled upon this term when I was trying to learn about the Chern-Simons theory. There also we have a term like $ A \wedge A \wedge A $.

Comment: For a real-valued 1-form, it's true that $\omega\wedge\omega=0$. But the $\omega$ in the curvature form is Lie-algebra-valued, and so this no longer holds in general. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra-valued_differential_form

Comment: Thanks @user17945 . That's precisely the answer I was looking for. You can repeat the same comment as an answer and I will mark it as Correct. Otherwise ( after waiting for a day or two), I will do it myself. I would feel bad for stealing your answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeating comment here:

For a real-valued 1-form, it's true that $\omega\wedge\omega=0$. But the $\omega$ in the curvature form is Lie-algebra-valued, and so this no longer holds in general. See https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra-valued_differential_form